# Error: Initialize a JWTManager with this flask application before using this method

Tags: flask, flask-restful, jwt

How can I solve this error in python flask jwt token set script:

> initialize a JWTManager with this flask application before using this method

Answer (score 2):

I FOUND SIMPLY SOLUTION FOR INITIALIZE THE JWTManager

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["MONGO_URI"] = "mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb"

jwt = JWTManager(app)
```